# How can I emit events to connected sockets using socket.io from within my Express 4 routes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io-1.0

This is a question other people have asked, but I can't manage to benefit from the answers they've been given, due to the different Express setup I have.

I've got socket.io implemented and working in a simple way on my server. This is how it works:

In `bin/www`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var debug = require('debug')('gokibitz');
var app = require('../../server');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.on('connection', require('../routes/socket.js'));
```

All my routes and other Express setup is in `../../server.js`.

```
var routes = require('./server/routes/index');
var user = require('./server/routes/user');
...

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/api/user/', user);
...
app.use('*', routes);
```

Then in `../routes/socket.js`, I've got this boilerplate:

```
module.exports = function (socket) {
    socket.emit('send:news', { hello: 'world' });

    setInterval(function () {
        socket.emit('send:time', {
            time: (new Date()).toString()
        });
    }, 1000);

    return socket;
};
```

This is working beautifully, I might add. But now I want to be able to emit events from the various routes in my quite-ordinary Express app, and I can't for the life of me figure out the right way to get a reference to the socket object I need.

**Example:** when a user makes a comment, I'd like to emit an event to all connected users notifying them of the new comment. From my routes file (`./server/routes/user.js`), how can I get access to the object I need to emit events?

Here's a skeleton of the relevant bits from a route file:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/', function (req, res) {
  ...
});

module.exports = router;
```

The only place I can access it is in the `../routes/socket.js` file, which is useless.

All of the routes are set in a `app.js` before there's any io or socket object to pass in.

Should I be able to `require('socket.io')` and use it somehow to emit to all connected sockets?

Is there a sensible way to store the connected sockets on `../routes/socket.js` so it can be required and emitted to from other routes?

Can anyone steer me in the right direction?

Comment: From a route, are you trying to broadcast a message to all connected users?  Or send only to the user that made the request on the route?  Who are you trying to send to from your route?  `io.emit(msg, data)` will send to all connected clients.  If you are doing this from another module, you will have to share the `io` variable to that other module.

Comment: I'm trying to broadcast a message to all connected users from a route. Example: a user adds a comment to a post. I'd like to broadcast a (namespaced) event to all users so that anyone viewing that post can listen for updates and have their page refresh with the new comment.

I know I need to share the io object, but I'm struggling to find the right way to do that with my setup.

Comment: In this last case, you need create a singleton returning the object or making this globally.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was able to ultimately get things working using this example: 
https://github.com/expressjs/generator/issues/45#issuecomment-53719435

I created a new file called `server/io.js`:

```
var io = require('socket.io')();

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});

module.exports = io;
```

Then I updated `server/bin/www` to this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var debug = require('debug')('gokibitz');
var app = require('../../server');
var io = require('../io');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});

io.attach(server);
```

Then, in my route, I use this:

```
var io = require('../io');
...
io.emit(...);
```

The missing piece for me, at least, was the ability to create the `io` object separately, return the correct object, then use `io.attach(server)` inside `bin/www` to start it up at the right point.

Hopefully this will help someone else following in my footsteps.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are confused with the concepts. The socket.io lib uses or emulate a websocket (bidirectional socket) with the client, and have not relation with routes.

You can send a notification to all sockets using the io object:

```
io.emit('message_to_all', true);
```

You have to an array on io.sockets, with all sockets.

You can uses namespaces or rooms to, I recomend you learn the documentation:

http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#

*Add something:*

If you want to send a message to all people in the same route, you can join to a channel with the same name of the path.

For example, in the client:

```
var socket = io(window.location.href); // Or route..
```

And the server:

```
var nsp = io.of('/the/specific/route');
nsp.on('connection', function(socket){
  // ...
});
nsp.emit('message_to_all_in_route', data);
```

**About the last question editing:**

You can send the io object in request or response object to routes, using the Express midleware API:

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var debug = require('debug')('gokibitz');
var app = require('../../server');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.io = io;
  next();
});

io.on('connection', require('../routes/socket.js'));
```

And in the route:

```
route.post('/post/:id/comments', function (req, res) {

   // Do your logic

  var postio = res.io.of('/post/' + req.params.id);
  postio.emit('new_comment', commentData);

});
```

Comment: Using the `io` object seems straightforward, but I don't know how to properly share the `io` object so that my routes in separate files can use it.

Comment: With the namespaces (like the example added in my response) you can define this routes with the io.of method.

Comment: I think we're talking past each other. I've updated my question to clarify how I'm struggling to get access to the object I need to emit events.

Comment: Your edit about using middleware looks like exactly what I need: let me make sure I can get it working.

Comment: It doesn't seem like the middleware is being called when it's added to `app` at that point: are you sure that it should work when added after the routes and after `app.listen`? Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Yeah, my routes get called *before* that middleware is added. It seems like the `/bin/www` structure created by the Express 4 generator causes so many problems.

Comment: The routes are called before the middleware definition, but the callbacks of the routes are called async after the server is running and the middleware are defined.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment, you can send to all connected clients with:

```
io.emit(msg, data);
```

This will require access to the `io` object that you created in your first module.  The usual way to share that with your module with your routes modeule would be to export a method from the routes module that lets you pass it the `io` object and then after you've required in the `routes` module and created the `io` object, you can just call that method to pass the `io` object to the routes module and it can save it locally for future use.

`io` is just a shared object like the `app` object is.  If you want a module to be able to use a shared object, the usual way is that you call some method in that module to share with it some objects that it can then use.

Comment: I'm afraid you're overestimating my ability to benefit from your general advice. I've updated my question with the structure of one of my route files: how would I modify it to get access to the `io` object in `bin/www`? I've tried adding `module.export.io = io;` to `bin/www` and `var io = require('../bin/www').io` to my route, but `io` is just undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a new file `sockets.js` in that file:

```
var socketio = require('socket.io');
var io;

module.exports = {
socketServer: function (app) {
    io = socketio.listen(app);

    io.on('connection', function (socket) {

        console.log(Object.keys(users));
        socket.on('message', function (data) {
            io.emit('updateChat', 'Hello World!')
        });
    });
  }
}
```

And in my `app.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

var io = require('./sockets').socketServer(http);
http.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('SERVER RUNNING.. PORT: ' + port)
});
```

This is working for me. Good Luck!